# Hp laptop i5 6200U memory upgrade

Tags: memory

Hp 15 ac 138 nia , need to know how many ram capacity can allocate these type of laptop. it has 2 slot , (DDR3L) - PC3-12800 1600MHz

Comment: What is your specific model number? Should be in a label in the battery compartment or elsewhere.

Comment: i think it is 15 ac series . product no is P7T76EA#BH5

Comment: Provide us with the specific specifications for your laptop provided by HP (i.e. the English product page)

Answer (score 1):

Check your Maintenance and user guide Pdf [at this link](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ac100-notebook-pc-series/8499326/model/9836078/manuals)

This means yours is "Non-Customer accessible/upgradable memory slots", but may not mean it Cannot be upgraded.

[image]

If you look further in the manual it says they can be replaced by authorized repair facility.

[image]

But warns is is for a professional to do so.

[image]

Comment: but my processor is i5 6200u.

Comment: Yes, that means yours is Non-Customer accessible/upgradable memory slots, so it cannot be upgraded.

Comment: when i asking this question from www3.hp
So, since your notebook has Intel hardware, the base model in the model series your notebook is part of, is called a 15t-ac000.
https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ac000-notebook-pc-series/7771404/model/8381866/drivers
 
But the memory link you last read would cover your notebook series including your model.
 
The only ones it doesn't cover are the ones with the Pentium and Celeron processors, because I believe those models only have one memory slot that takes up to 1 x 8GB memory, where yours can take 2 x 8 GB "   are u agree with him ?

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Hp-laptop-i5-6200U-memory-upgrade/m-p/6189309#M403314

Comment: @john check my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Moab. I am living in Asian country (Sri lanka). There is no Quality HP product . Most of HP product's are assemble Laptops.

Comment: @Moab 'Non-Customer accessible' simply means that you need to unscrew the whole back panel to get to the RAM slots. The RAM itself is not soldered, so there is nothing stopping you from replacing/upgrading it. The manual may also say the max is 16GB, but it also doesn't mean anything, if the CPU and motherboard support more than 16GB. There could be restrictions in BIOS, but that could be solved with changing BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Your system is a HP 15-ac138nia Laptop. Max is 2 x 8GB DDR3L

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackard15ac138nia.html